# How can I determine the domain controller when it's not in DNS?

Tags: windows, dns, active-directory

On a penetration test going in blind for an organization, meaning no knowledge of network topology of design, no idea what the domain(s) might be, and domain controller is not apparent in DNS...how can it be determined what the Domain Controller is?

Assuming a dedicated DNS server instead of the DC handling DNS

Is there any way to determine what the domain controller is in this scenario?

Comment: sniff the wire? clients communicate with the DC pretty regularly in predictable ways

Comment: @schroeder That's where I lack familiarity. What kind of traffic on what ports am I looking for that would indicate traffic to a DC, as opposed to another windows machine?

Comment: The ports for ldap (389 and 636) and kerberos (88) seem like they should be indicators.

Answer (score 3):

Jumping on the NMAP bandwagon: also look for machines that have TCP port 389 (LDAP), 636 (LDAPS), 3268 (LDAP Global Catalog), or 3269 (LDAPS Global Catalog). The last two are particularly juicy, since only a DC can be a Global Catalog server.

Answer (score 1):

Sniff for [TCP or UDP 88 (Kerberos), amongst others](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Or if you have an account on the domain (just in case), from the command prompt run `nltest /dclist:yourdomain.com`

Answer (score 1):

Look for NetBIOS over TCP broadcasts, NBT

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940063.aspx

Look for Group Names with `1C` , as this indicates the Domain Controllers.  I would expect this name to be broadcasted on the same subnet, and be queried on a per machine basis by using `NBTSTAT -A IP`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where the pentest is being launched, one should be able to determine the DC by querying the SRV records for LDAP, Kerberos, GC, etc.

This [Microsoft TechNet link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961719.aspx) has some examples.